# Detect touch monitor with mouse attached

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wonder if it's possible to detect a kind of the device that runs a `JS` app.
What do I mean? - I want to serve touch monitors (that can be used as a normal touch devices and also can have a mouse attached - so they can behave as a normal PC) and classic touch devices (e.g. mobile phones - without possibility to use a mouse).

Is it possible? I know how to detect touch devices:

```
var isTouch = !!("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints);
```

But how to detect that there is a touch monitor or at least it has a mouse attached?

Comment: That's not possible, I'm afraid. JS has no clue what kind of hardware is attached.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of this:S maybe some1 knows a workaround for this issue:/

Comment: The only thing I can find is stuff checking the touch event. Like i said, JavaScript has no such access to hardware.

Comment: Why the distinction? Why would a touch monitor be different than a tablet touch screen? If there's a distinction in behavior, maybe the user should be in control anyway of the app mode?

Comment: Because we have a very specific app and we want to coerce such the behaviour (touch monitors + normal PCs = one layout / other touch devices the other one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already have a bool reflecting touch capabilities. Obtaining the same for the mouse is doable, although not exactly elegant. You could do something like this:

```
var hasMouse;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function mouseCheck(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseCheck);
    hasMouse = true;
});
```

Combined with user-agent inspection, you could get a decent estimate of the users device. Naturally some mobile browsers allow one to spoof a non-mobile user agent for 'desktop' like viewing. I'm not too fond of the idea of coercing interface formats in a situation where you aren't certain of the devices capabilities. How about simply showing a modal at application start, and using the isTouch && hasMouse, along with user-agent information to indicate the 'recommended' layout?